# Couldn't people just buy mainframes from the same manufacturer and connect them before the arpanet?

Tags: mainframe

I was reading the TCP/IP Protocol Suite by Forouzan and at one point it says:

> In the mid-1960s, mainframe computers in research organizations were
> stand-alone devices. Computers from different manufacturers were
> unable to communicate with one another. The Advanced Research Projects
> Agency (ARPA) in the Department of Defense (DOD) was interested in
> finding a way to connect computers together so that the researchers
> they funded could share their findings, thereby reducing costs and
> eliminating duplication of effort.

I don't understand what they mean by mainframes were stand alone. Could they be connected to each other if they were from the same manufacturer? Why go through all that to help scientists share their findings when they can just buy mainframes from the same manufacturer and connect them?

Comment: I believe you may be over thinking the situation. If you consider the timeframe, the 1950's, was a time before modems and networking were known things. So, even if you had 2 computers, from the same manufacturer, in the same room, there was nothing to connect them together to communicate. It would be no different than two desktop PC's in your house with all the ports removed to have no connectivity other than the keyboard and monitor. A mouse was not yet known then either.

Comment: To connect two identical computers, there needs to be an I/O device that outputs signals that can be carried hundreds of miles.  To 'just buy a mainframe' requires finding a few hundred thousand dollars, and then you've got the problem of getting the data from the system that they really use to the system that's connected.

Comment: It is hard to understand today how expensive computers used to be.  Think supertanker or aircraft carrier - you need good reason to buy another one.

Comment: I don't have the time and energy to research an answer but look at IBM's SNA.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Network_Architecture

Comment: Argument from incredulity.

Comment: @badjohn - until LU6.2, SNA was more about connecting devices (possibly intelligent devices, like RJE stations) to a central computing facility, than a true computer-to-computer network.

Comment: I'd have to research dates but I was using systems connected by SNA before I even knew what TCP/IP was.  Functions such as passthrough (roughly like telnet) and data exchange (roughly like FTP).

Comment: Almost every single word in that incredibly stupid paragraph is wrong. - Based only on what you quoted, I would throw away the entire book and look elsewhere for information on TCP/IP.

Answer (score 10):

1. Research organizations, universities, defense contractors, and the Pentagon had some perfectly valid reasons for buying computers from different manufacturers including commercial, functional, and performance considerations. Some of the defense contractors even manufactured their own computers. And it wasn't until at least 1965 when one manufacturer could've plausibly addressed every computing need with a single line of computers. That's when IBM started shipping their System/360 computers. But even from that point there were still at least some commercial reasons and occasionally performance reasons why other manufacturers' computers were better fits for certain missions.
2. The "unable to communicate" part seems oversimplified. Computers from different manufacturers have long had ways to communicate with each other. Data transmission pre-dates electronic computing, after all. It goes back to the telegraph and the development of automated and semi-automated telegraphic equipment in the 1800s. The pre-TCP/IP intercommunication methods weren't necessarily terrific (especially by modern standards), but they existed. And some of them had some terrific design features. However, ARPA definitely played a critical role in developing and promoting what eventually became the de facto standard network protocol suite, and ARPA had a fairly early start. It's really the standardization and proliferation of TCP/IP that made it easier, more convenient, and less expensive to interconnect computers. And no matter how great the network protocol suite is the applications riding on the network can make all the difference. Web browsing (and HTTP) really supercharged the proliferation of TCP/IP in the 1990s.

Comment: TCP/IP was not the first transport protocol on the Arpanet.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand what they mean by mainframes were stand alone.

You left out the a very important restriction of that claim:

*"In the mid-1960s, mainframe computers **in research organizations** were stand-alone devices."*

Universities had usually rather small and limited installations, and were usually rather cash strapped. This is in contrast to commercial settings where networking was already a thing right from the start of electronic computing. Also helpful to keep in mind that networking like today wasn't really something in need. People were still exploring the idea of a computer at all.

> Could they be connected to each other if they were from the same manufacturer?

Yes, of course. Remote Job Entry (RJE) is a core function of mainframe systems and dates back to punch-card times - way before terminals became a thing. RJE means subsidiaries like a local bank branch would punch their transactions, pack them into one or more jobs, add jobs to get printouts and so on. The central mainframe would fetch those jobs by operating the local reader, execute them and punch out result at local card punches or printers.

With (comparably) cheap computers becoming available during the 1960s, those branches got their own computers holding data for local display and processing.

This was pretty standard in 1960. Larger companies, especial banks, employed multi-tier structures with local computing centers doing processing for branches and exchanging data between them and toward a headquarters installation.

While manufacturers like IBM did of course prefer to sell their own products for all elements, RJE became an area where third party equipment had a foothold. In fact, third party RJE development is the very heritage of today's x86 world. x86 is a direct offspring of the Datapoint 2200 CPU, which was developed to replace classic punch-card RJE by a screen-based system with tightly integrated local data processing/handling capabilities, still using the same communication infrastructure.

By the early 1970s, vast private networks built around manufacturer protocols (mostly IBM) with multi-tier processing did exist in the US and worldwide.

> Why go through all that to help scientists share their findings when they can just buy mainframes from the same manufacturer and connect them?

Money? After all, universities were at all times less well funded than banks, insurance companies or utilities. The usage of rather low-end systems for nodes and hosts does tell the same story.

Next it's a different challenge to combine vastly different systems versus integrating into a single system of a major manufacturer.

Last but not least, buying stuff does not create knowledge or educate; building your own stuff is great research work - exactly what universities are about: research and learning.

---

Side note:

Contrary to the common assumption, those connections weren't slow *per se*. Sure, dial-up lines for very small installation might have been as slow as 300 or 600 Bd, but network connections between remote mainframes were already ca. 1970 operating at 4800 or 9600 bd line speed.

Local connection between mainframes could be made even faster, either using communication processors which could deliver up to several hundred kilobytes between multiple machines on the same campus, or by coupling two mainframes using a [channel to channel adaptor](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/370/CTCA/GA22-6983-0_Special_Feature_Description_Channel-to-Channel_Adapter_Mar72.pdf) delivering transfer speed way past a megabyte per second. Of course the later were restricted to a distance of 200 ft between the CPUs.

Comment: Oddly enough, the first thing I wrote as a professional programmer was an RJE emulator on PDP-11.  Univac, not IBM, though if I recall correctly it was using bisync at the  link level.

Comment: @another-dave What better proof there can be :)) Of course, there were other manufacturers as well - not to mention that Univac as well had an interesting line of low to mid range /360 compatible systems. Almost small enough to be collectable :))

Comment: The question also overlooks the matter of what the researchers were researching - which was often the design and structure of computer systems. Forcing everyone to use the same hardware would defeat the point. Even if everyone had the same hardware, the software would still need to be implemented for each OS.

Comment: There was also a reasonable about of research work done by a university in conjunction with a specific manufacturer - who provided the equipment.  And too, equipment was donated by manufacturers too - lower-tier colleges which couldn't really afford anything on their own would get hand-me-downs.

Answer (score 2):

> Why go through all that to help scientists share their findings when they can just buy mainframes from the same manufacturer and connect them?

That's essentially the whole problem right there -- they would have to buy new computers from the same manufacturer to connect them.  They would also have to somehow manually move their data from existing computers of different manufacturers.

Much better (and cheaper) to allow existing different computers from different manufacturers to interoperate.

Comment: Also bear in mind that data comms back in the day was around 300bps.  If you had a small amount of data to exchange you could just read it out over the phone, and if you had a lot then you could post (mail) a reel of paper tape - not bad bandwidth but a ping time of a few days.

Answer (score -1):

ARPANET was the first network for computers and it was extremely basic - after all they had to invent it from scratch. Smoke signals just wouldn't work. They had telephone and telegraph as examples to start with. No computers from any vendor included networking. In those early days the 'networking' was known as sneaker net where an operator took a paper tape, or early magnetic tape, from one computer to another.

Comment: Not true -- IBM had networks connecting its computers well before ARPANET.  Of course, they only worked with IBM computers and could not interoperate with anyone else.